# How to show the values of the $reference array in the form with id "#step3form"?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have this form for a user to select a payment method:

```
<form method="post" id="step2form" action="">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <h6>Select payment method</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="references">
                 <span class="mr-auto">References</span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="credit_card">
                 <span class="mr-auto">Credit Card</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step mr-2">
            Voltar ao passo 1
        </button>
            <input type="submit" href="#step3" id="goToStep3" class="btn btn-primary float-right next-step" value="Go to step 3"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When the user selects a payment method and clicks "go to step 3" the code goes to the `handlePaymentMethods()` through an ajax request. In this method, if the payment method selected was "references" are generated some references. This code "`$reference = $payment->generateRerences();`" returns an array with some references for the user to use to pay.

My doubt is how to show the info in this $reference array in the form with id "#step3form". Do you know how that can be achieved?

```
public function handlePaymentMethods(Request $request){
       $request->validate([
            'payment_method' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($request->payment_method == "references"){
            $payment_info = [
                't_value' => '10',
                'o_obs' => ''
            ];

            $payment = new Payment($payment_info);
            $reference = $payment->generateReferences();
        }
        else{
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
            'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        ], 200);
    }
```

jQuery and ajax code that makes an ajax request to the handlePaymentMehods() and shows the next tab (step3) if code 200 is returned:

```
$("#credit_card_section").hide();
$("#references_section").hide();

var page_form_id_step2 = "step2form";

    $('#goToStep3').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id_step2);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route('conferences.storePaymentMethods', compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var result = data;
                if(result['payment_method'] == 'credit_card'){
                    $("#credit_card_section").show();
                    $("#references_section").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#references_section").show();
                    $("#credit_card_section").hide();
                }
                var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
                nextTab($active);
            },
            error: function (data) {
               // show errors
            }
        });
    });
```

The step3 form has the div "#references_section" that is visible when the payment method selected is references and the values of the $reference array should be presented here:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step3form" action="">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div id="credit_card_section">

            </div>
              <div id="references_section">
        <!-- how to show the values of the $reference array here?-->
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: The version 5.5.

Comment: why can't you just add the $reference as part of the response json?

Comment: Thanks, but then how to show in the step3 form the results? Its necessary to show using jQuery?

Comment: Maybe is better store the $reference content in session and in step3 get the session values in blade?

Comment: what is actually stored in the references? I wouldn't see the need to store it in a sesison

Comment: A reference code and a value. In the session I can store like:    Session::put('reference', $reference['reference']);
            Session::put('value', $reference['value']);.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is optimal to use a session variable here.  I recommend just sending the data back through AJAX.

First, you need to create the form element within the hidden div.  It just won't have any options until you send the $reference array to the page.  Something like:

```
<div id="references_section">
    <select class="form-control" name="references" id='references'></select>
</div>
```

Once you have this, you can use jquery to append the new array into this select statement.  Something like:

```
success: function (newArray) {
    $("#references").empty();

    var list = '<option value="">Please Select</option>';

    $.each(newArray, function(value,key) {
        list += "<option value='" +value + "'>" + key + "</option>";
    });

    $("#references").html(list);
    $("#references").trigger('change');
}
```

You'll **have to tweak to suit**... but something similar to this will get the array into the form's select statement via jquery.